# How can I make a grid of content in Pelican?

Tags: pelican

I am trying to use Pelican to generate a static webpage that would have rows of content.

I want it to look  [something like this](http://limitlesssoftware.net/rapidreader/) (WIP)

Currently I have just manually created the necessary HTML.

How could I have a single content file that would generate this page ?

Answer (score 0):

Pelican uses the Jinja template system, so the first step is to create your own theme, putting your existing HTML structure into the `base.html` template. You'll likely want to customize your `page.html` template as well.

Once your theme's templates are customized to your liking, you can then create pages in any of the formats that Pelican supports: Markdown, reStructuredText, and Asciidoc. It's not always easy to use these markup formats to get precisely the HTML you want, so you might start with Markdown, since that format allows you to put HTML directly inside your content.

Answer (score 0):

To make a table grid in Markdown-formatted file, add the Pelican `just_table` plugin.

If your existing `PLUGINS` is defined to something like:

```
PLUGINS = ['sitemap', 'code_include', 'tag_cloud']
```

just add `, 'just_table'` to `PLUGINS` set to make a:

```
PLUGINS = ['sitemap', 'code_include', 'tag_cloud', 'just_table']
```

and in creating your first Markdown text file named `my-first-grid-table.md`, take your CSV-formatted content and wrap it with `[jtable]`/`[/jtable]` tags.  Such working example is:

```
Title: My first grid table
Date: 2018-11-06 11:00
Tags: grid, table
Category: blog

My grid looks like:

[jtable]
Name, Age, Description
John, 40, Cantankerous
Jill, 35, Bruised from tumbling down the hill
Basket, 120, an inanimated object
[/jtable]
```